# SSH.NET - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, linux, git, ssh, suse

I'm using SSH.NET to connect and send commands to my Linux. Until yesterday it was SLES 12 and everything worked fine. Today I've upgraded it to SLES12 SP1 and when I'm trying to connect with server (through application with SSH.NET) I get exception - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. All time I could use Putty or Git Bash to connect to machine and there is no problem. Putty and my application are using the same port (22). What I can do? I'm pretty sure that problem lies in my SLES configuration.

Comment: on the server side you could run sshd in verbose mode and see why it is freaking out. I'd guess new OpenSSL or something that SSH.NET isnt handling properly.

Comment: I get this: http://pastebin.com/FhaKw4RW

Comment: Problem solved: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7016904

Comment: Awesome hope i helped a little!

Answer (score 7):

I don´t know about SLES12 but i'm almost shure that it uses sshd and that is what's causing your problem. In the latest version, the minimum key sizes were increased and this brakes ssh.net causing your exception.

A patch has been submited and will be integrated in the next release. Until then, the only solution is to use a pre-release version of ssh.net

More info:

- https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/1687
- https://sshnet.codeplex.com/workitem/1973

Comment: Thank you @Nippius. you are great.  version update fixed the issue